# Vb.net Count String In Excel

Tags: vb.net

Hello so I am trying to find an exact string in a excel workbook and count how many times it in that sheet and was stuck on how I should do this can anyone help?

```
        'Open a blank Excel File.
        oXL = CType(CreateObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
        'Sets oxl visible off so you can't see it open.
        oXL.Visible = True
        ' Get a new workbook.
        oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(dicJobList)
        'Set oSheet to active sheet.
        oSheet = CType(oWB.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet)
        FillGrid()

        oSheet.Cells.Find("DC")
'This is where I would need to count how many times 
'It was found.
```

Comment: Is this VB.NET using Excel's interop assemblies, or VBA running witihn an Excel macro?

Comment: After `Range.Find`  you can use `Range.FindNext` in a loop  until it returns `Nothing` and increase a counter. Here is an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4x1k99a.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2 (i cannot test it without excel).